# Integrating $\sin x\cos x$

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Using substitution with $u=\sin{x}$, The integral of $\sin{x}\cos{x}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2{x}$. This is the solution I require.

However, why is it that when I use the double angle formula $\sin{2x} = 2\sin{x} \cos{x}$, and integrate $\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}$, I get a completely different answer of $-\frac{1}{4}\cos{2x}$ even though $\sin{2x} = 2\sin{x} \cos{x}$.

Comment: Note that $\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^{2}(x)$. Substituting this in you can see that the the answers agree when you remember to account for the missing constant of integration.

Comment: They are all the same but differ by a constant. Try graphing them to see it

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not a completely different answer. By the double-angle formulae for cosine and the pythagorean identity, you have
$$ \cos{2x} = \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x} = 1-2\sin^2{x}, $$
so $-\frac{1}{4}\cos{2x}$ differs from $\frac{1}{2}\sin^2{x}$ by a constant. Since an indefinite integral is only determined up to a constant anyway, this is fine.

Comment: In fact you can do that integral in 6 ways and every answer would be the same

Comment: There're probably infinitely many ways, but yes, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus implies they all differ by a constant.